# Problem with importing a module in a Python3 script

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I got this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'admin' from ' admin.blueprint' after I'm in the module blueprint.py imported Post from models.py please help me to understand the structure of the application in order to avoid such errors in the future.

`<module main.py>`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from admin.blueprint import admin
from config import Config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')


import views

if __name__ == '__main__'
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

`<module blueprint.py>`

```
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from config import ConfigAdmin
from models import Post

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')


@admin.route('/')
def admin_login():
    return render_template('admin/admin-login.html')

@admin.route('/admin-panel', methods=['POST'])
def admin_panel():
if request.form['username'] == ConfigAdmin.ADMIN_NAME and request.form['password'] == ConfigAdmin.ADMIN_PASS:
     return render_template('admin/admin-panel.html')
else:
     return redirect(url_for('admin.admin_login'))

@admin.route('/create-post')
def create_post():
    return render_template('admin/create-post.html')

@admin.route('/add-post', methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
if request.method == 'POST':
    body = Post(post_title=request.form['title'], post_text=request.form['article'], post_img=redirect.form['file'])
    db.session.add(body)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
else:
    return "Err"
```

`<module models.py>`

```
from main import db


class Admin(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    passw = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)


class Post(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   title = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
   text = db.Column(db.String(500), unique=True)
   img = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

[error][1]
[structure][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgrbH.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDr7O.png

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post your error as text and not as an image.  What is your directory structure like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the following app? [Flask Tutorial App - Flaskr blog](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/)
I highly recommend following this structure if you're starting out.

looks as follows:

```
/home/user/Projects/flask-tutorial
├── flaskr/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── schema.sql
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── blog.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── auth/
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   └── register.html
│   │   └── blog/
│   │       ├── create.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       └── update.html
│   └── static/
│       └── style.css
├── tests/
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── data.sql
│   ├── test_factory.py
│   ├── test_db.py
│   ├── test_auth.py
│   └── test_blog.py
├── venv/
├── setup.py
└── MANIFEST.in
```

If you would like it to function in your current app I suggest you create a `admin.py` inside the same folder as your `main.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from config import ConfigAdmin
from models import Post

bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
```

then import it in `main.py` as follows

```
from admin import bp as adminbp
app.register_blueprint(adminbp, url_prefix='/admin')
```

Comment: if the blueprint.py file is placed next to main.py, then there will be exactly the same error.

Comment: I said create an `admin.py` file?